# "Streaming" read of over 10 million rows from a table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is the best strategy to read millions of records from a table (in SQL Server 2012, BI instance), in a streaming fashion (like SQL Server Management Studio does)?

I need to cache these records locally (C# console application) for further processing.

**Update** - 
Sample code that works with SqlDataReader

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;


namespace ReadMillionsOfRows
{
    class Program
    {
        static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          Process();
          done.WaitOne();
        }

        public static async Task Process()
        {
            string connString = @"Server=;Database=;User Id=;Password=;Asynchronous Processing=True";
            string sql = "Select * from tab_abc";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql))
                {
                    comm.Connection = conn;
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            //process it here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            done.Set();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your main priority? Performance? Simplicity? Presentation? Mind elaborating the question?

Comment: Primary priority is to read in an non-blocking fashion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a SqlDataReader it is forward only and fast. It will only hold a reference to a record while it is in the scope of reading it.

Comment: Also depends on the momery you have. Cos SqlDataReader keep one record a time rather than millions of records, SqlDataAdapter/DataSet will keep all the records in memory.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what your cache looks like. If you're going to store everything in memory, and a DataSet is approriate as a cache, just read everything to the DataSet.

If not, use the `SqlDataReader` as suggested above, read the records one by one storing them in your big cache.

Do note, however, that there's already a very popular caching mechanism for large database tables - your database. With the proper index configuration, the database can probably outperform your cache.

Comment: _Do note, however, that there's already a very popular caching mechanism for large database tables - your database_. That's so true!

Answer (score -2):

You can use Entity Framework and paginate the select using `Take` and `Skip` to fetch the rows by buffer. If you need in memory caching for such a large dataset I would suggest using `GC.GetTotalMemory` in order to test if there is any free memory left.