# Implement behavior like Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous

I'm developing a application that displays data resulting from a vast amount of pre-defined queries...

I was wondering how could i make my interface copy the behavior of management studio. By that I mean I want to display the query results as management studio does: piece-by-piece (except when some "order by" clause is defined)...

Using [BeginExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx) makes the code async but does not make the Reader available until all the results are there... same thing with [comm.ExecuteReaderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204836.aspx)

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045481/streaming-read-of-over-10-million-rows-from-a-table-in-sql-server) looks similar to what I want but the guy accepted a very doubtful answer...

Comment: The accepted answer in the other question is correct. You don't need the async methods, just SqlDataReader is fine. If it takes some time to get the first record, have a look at the query plan in question. If you have blocking operators like sort or spool late in the plan, SQL Server cannot deliver any records before these operations are fully processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing my source code with the code provided i noticed that in my connection string was missing the "Asynchronous Processing=True"... after adding it everything went back to normal...